# License problem embedding Mono?

Tags: dll, mono

I'd like to embed Mono into an .exe file but the problem is the license, because a LGPL library can only be linked with LGPL code. However, I'd like to build a commercial app, so I ask if is possible to use a stub that launches a DLL version of the Mono runtime and executes my app. Or do you know a better way to do this?

I need a cross-platform framework and Mono seems good, but there are some problem to pack it in one file, so you know a "free" way to do this?

Comment: Really?? I was pretty sure that the difference between LGPL and GPL is that you can link LGPL code to non-GPL code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where you have the idea that you must LGPL your app. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License):

> The main difference between the GPL
>   and the LGPL is that the latter can be
>   linked to (in the case of a library,
>   'used by') a non-(L)GPLed program,
>   regardless of whether it is free
>   software or proprietary software.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License)
>   This non-(L)GPLed program can then be
>   distributed under any chosen terms if
>   it is not a derivative work.

From [the LGPL license](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/library.html#TOC1):

> You may copy and distribute the Library (or a portion or derivative of
>   it, under Section 2) in object code or
>   executable form under the terms of
>   Sections 1 and 2 above provided that
>   you accompany it with the complete
>   corresponding machine-readable source
>   code, which must be distributed under
>   the terms of Sections 1 and 2 above on
>   a medium customarily used for software
>   interchange.
>
> If distribution of object code is made
>   by offering access to copy from a
>   designated place, then offering
>   equivalent access to copy the source
>   code from the same place satisfies the
>   requirement to distribute the source
>   code, even though third parties are
>   not compelled to copy the source along
>   with the object code.

That says that you merely need to provide access to the source code of the library if it's distributed in binary form. Just make sure you're not creating a **derivative work** and instead are merely linking to the lib.

If you're not content with LGPL, then you could always purchase a license from Novell.

From http://www.mono-project.com/License:

> Mono is available to be licensed
>   commercially if the LGPL/GPL/X11
>   combination is not suitable for you.
>   [Mono Tools for Visual Studio Ultimate
>   Edition](http://www.go-mono.com/store/#Mono_Tools_Ultimate) includes a commercial
>   license to redistribute Mono under
>   non-LGPL terms on Windows, Linux, and
>   Mac OS X PCs for products with volumes
>   under 100,000 and revenues under $2M
>   annually. If your organization intends
>   to redistribute software which embeds
>   or bundles Mono, but is unable to
>   comply with the terms of GNU LGPL v2,
>   the Ultimate Edition may be right for
>   you.
>
> For other licensing options, contact
>   us.

Comment: Yes I'm a bit confused about GPL LGPL etc. but for example if I make a simple software like a phone book for examples and I link mono with my exe you think that I can make without commercial license (according your answer :yes)? and an example that I need commercial license (according your answer: if I mod in any way source of mono and I don't want to redistribuite it)?

It's right?